Will a spaceship moving at $0.87c$ the speed of light, age twice less?
Strangely enough, the physics community seems to me having opposing views on this, namely many say that constant speed SR time dilation effects in the rest frame of an relativistically moving massive object are physical real thus all virtual photons exchange between the atoms of a mass object are time dilated inside its rest frame and therefore aging slows down compared to an external non-relativistic moving observer. So for example, an astronaut moving at about $0.87c$ (i.e. Lorentz factor γ=2) will age half the years relative to a stationary observer on Earth.
Nevertheless, many say that time inside the relativistically moving massive object's rest frame thus proper time, is unaffected and time flows normally inside the rest frame of the spaceship carrying the astronaut therefore $1$ sec tick on a clock inside the spaceship has the exact same duration as on Earth and SR time dilation effects apply only as long the spaceship is observed by a stationary observer on Earth, being in motion. However in my opinion, this would then imply that when the spaceship returns and becomes stationary on Earth no time dilation effect would have been recorded from the clocks inside the spaceship relative to that of Earth? Therefore, the spaceship and its astronauts would not have aged differently (i.e. half the time in our case) than on Earth.
I am confused, please clarify? Which of the two answers is the correct one? Will SR time dilation affect aging of the spaceship and its occupants? Thus, the astronauts will have aged less when returning and become stationary on Earth?

You need to be explicit about whether the two frames of reference are moving at constant velocity with respect to eachother or not. If they are, they can not meet and compare anything except at the one instance where the frames coincide. If you want the astronaut to return to Earth after leaving it, they need to accelerate, and acceleration is not relative like velocity is.

If they are moving at constant velocity with respect to eachother, then by symmetry and the principle of relativity, they must both describe the other in identical fashion. This is why "regular" time dilation is symmetric.

http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/airtim.html#c4 This says that atomic clocks in airplane have been compared to reference clock on Earth after the airplane landed and became stationary. So less aging time dilation is physical real, inside the spacecraft.

Yes I know, because the airplane is accelerating in order to both obtain velocity relative to the Earth, and to become stationary again. This is why I said you have to specify which case you are asking about.

@MariusLadegårdMeyer Let's say in both cases departure and return to Earth spaceship flight, the Galilean relative speed of the spacecraft to the Earth's linear motion around  the Galactic center is kept fixed at 0.87c.

@MariusLadegårdMeyer quote: "If they are moving at constant velocity with respect to eachother, then by symmetry and the principle of relativity, they must both describe the other in identical fashion." But, does then this not bring back the Twins Paradox? So they should not age differently assuming only constant speed SR? OR as you call it "regular symmetric" SR time dilation which is the root of the twins paradox. So in my case asking, the astronaut  should not have aged differently?

The inertial frame during departure is different from the frame during return. The broken symmetry comes from this dissimilarity between Earth and the spaceship in this regard. Alternatively, you need to understand that the spaceship must accelerate in order to change direction from "away from Earth" to "back towards Earth". This acceleration is not there for Earth.

Yes, this is exactly the twin "paradox", and in the resolution of this "paradox" the person undergoing the acceleration has a different age upon return.

@MariusLadegårdMeyer Regardless acceleration or symmetry, IMHO, SR time dilation effects and different aging will happen anyway since the only true rest frame (time passage freezes to null) in our universe according to SR is the speed of light c in the vacuum. But this is more for a debate.

Light does not have a rest frame in SR. And no, the entirety of SR is built on the principle of relativity. The person in the spaceship is at rest, relative to their inertial reference frame. And in that frame, the Earth is moving. For a person on Earth, it is vice versa. It does not make sense to say that one of them "is moving relativistically/non-relativistically/at all". It is relative.

You've not quite understood time dilation properly. What it means is that the duration between two events that occur in the same place in one frame is always less than the duration between the same two events in some other frame in which they occur in different places.
So, a pair of events that are five seconds apart on the spaceship will be ten seconds apart in the frame of the Earth. The effect is symmetrical, so a pair of events that are five seconds apart on Earth will be ten seconds apart in the frame of the spaceship.
Notice that in both cases it is the actual interval that changes- it is ten seconds in one frame and five seconds in the other. It is not that there is something wrong with the clocks in either frame- they are actually measuring different lengths of time.
So far I have assumed that the motion of the two frames is inertial. If you introduce acceleration then things become more complicated. However, the general rule is that time measured along a crooked path between two events will be shorter than the time measured along a straight path. The classic ‘twin paradox’ is a commonly cited example of that effect.

So indeed, in my case described in the question and according to your answer the astronaut returning back to Earth will have aged half the time compared to Earth time?

Does this mean also that if we want to sent astronauts to Alpha Centauri system, 4lys away with the spaceship accelerating at 0.87c speed they spaceship will arrive at approximately 4.6 years (i.e. 4 years and 7 months) in Earth time but actually for the astronauts inside the ship it will take only half this time thus 2 years and 3.5 months in Earth time?

If they accelerate up to that speed quickly, decelerate at Alpha Centauri, and then do that whole thing in reverse, yes. But when accelerations take place is very very important because it’s the breaker of Lorentz symmetries.

Broadly yes. And the effect is symmetric. Imagine there is a second spaceship trailing four light years  behind the first in the frame of the spaceship. According to the clocks on the spaceships, the Earth with take 4.6 years  to pass between the two ships, whereas on Earth the clock will show the duration as being half that.

This apparent problem only ever arises when you attempt to compare the reading of clocks that are spatially separated.
In the classic example of the twin "paradox", you may know that the same time dilation effect is observed in both frames. Letting the coordinate systems be denoted by $(t_e,x_e)$ for earth and $(t_a,x_a)$ for the astronaut, the earth twin sees the astronaut's trajectory to be $x_e = vt_e$. Similarly, for the astronaut twin the earth twin has a trajectory given by $x_a = -vt_a$. Applying the Lorentz transformation we see that:
\begin{align*}
 t_a&=\gamma(t_e-v x_e) 
\\  &=\gamma(t_e-v^2 t_e) 
\\  &= \gamma t_e(1-v^2)
\\  &= \frac{t_e}{\gamma} 
\end{align*}
So if for example $1$ second elapses for the earth twin, $1/\gamma$ seconds will appear to him to elapse for the astronaut.
The same analysis, from the point of view of the astronaut yields:
\begin{align*}
t_e&=\gamma(t_a+v x_a) 
\\ &= \gamma(t_a-v^2 t_a) 
\\ &= \frac{t_a}{\gamma} 
\end{align*}
The only thing we learn from this, is that the way the two observers assign their hyperplanes of simultaneity is different. You can immediately see this and gain a bit more intuition about this from working with spacetime diagrams.
I'll try to give you an example with the following diagram. The hyperbola drawn in red is $\color{red}{t^2-x^2=1}$, which means all along it, all inertial observers that measure times and lengths relative to the common origin at $(0,0)$ on this diagram, agree that $1$ is the squared magnitude of the spacetime interval.
The blue line is the world line of the astronaut twin, he's travelling at $0.8c$ here so with $c=1$ his world line becomes $\color{blue}{x=0.8t}$. You can see the red hyperbola intersects it at point $A$. Now the astronaut is at rest with respect to himself, so $x'=0$ implies $t'=1$ at that point on the hyperbola. All we've wanted to demonstrate so far is that for the astronaut, at that point $A$ on his worldline, his clock will read $t'=1$, one second has elapsed for him.

Now the dashed purple line crossing point $A$, is his hyperplane of simultaneity at that same point. The way to think about it concretely is as follows: if the astronaut would station observers all across space (you can imagine he has a very large ship), so that they all have synchronized clocks, they would be stationed along that line at $t'=1$. It simply happens to be a hyperplane (if we consider more than one dimension) such that in his frame, he is able to synchronize clocks so that they all agree. So all spacetime events that happen across that plane/line, are simultaneous for him, namely they all correspond to events that in his frame occur at $t'=1$.
Now, you can see that on the one hand, this hyperplane crosses the $t$ axis of the earth observer at $t=0.6$, confirming that from the astronaut's perspective, the earth twin's clock is running slow, he seems to be measuring that less than one second has elapsed. (Recall: the world line of the earth twin is just $x=0$!).
On the other hand, drawing a surface of simultaneity from $t=1$ for the earth twin, which is simpler (the dashed black line, which is just parallel to the $x$ axis), we see that it crosses the blue worldline of the astronaut twin well before $t'=1$. In fact, drawing another invariant hyperbola $\color{#CC5500}{t^2-x^2=0.6^2}$ we see that it intersects the blue worldline precisely where the simultaneous earth hyperplane of $t=1$ does, confirming that the time dilation effect is mutual between the frames: the earth twin sees that the astronaut twin's clock reads $t'=0.6$ when his clock reads $t=1$.
Finally, let's just confirm that our diagram is consistent with the calculation we did in the first part. We've seen that the Lorentz transformations imply each twin will see his counterpart's clock slowed down by a factor of $1/\gamma$. So, taking $v=0.8$ like we did in the diagram we find:
$$ \frac{1}{\gamma} = \sqrt{1-0.8^2} = 0.6 $$
This may be a lot to take in at once. Like I said, it's best to really draw a few of those diagrams for yourself to get a feel for it all. There are several online tools that let you do that. I rather not specify any link in particular that may become broken in due time, but I'm sure you'll be able to find many resources for that.


Strangely enough, the physics community seems to me having opposing views on this, namely many say that constant speed SR time dilation effects in the rest frame of an relativistically moving massive object are physical real

There is no disagreement among the physics community about the correct prediction of any measurement for time dilation. However, the “physically real” question is a question of metaphysics (philosophy) and not physics (science). So there is indeed some small amount of disagreement on that.

for example, an astronaut moving at about 0.87c (i.e. Lorentz factor γ=2) will age half the years relative to a stationary observer on Earth

Yes, this statement describes the following measurement: the scientists on Earth set up a pair of synchronized clocks, one here on Earth and one at rest wrt Earth at 0.87 ly distance. As the ship passes Earth we record the time on the Earth clock and the ship clock. As the ship passes the synchronized clock we record the time on that clock and the ship clock. The difference between the Earth clock and the synchronized clock is 1 year, while the difference between the two readings of the ship clock is 0.5 year.

many say that time inside the relativistically moving massive object's rest frame thus proper time, is unaffected and time flows normally inside the rest frame of the spaceship carrying the astronaut therefore 1 sec tick on a clock inside the spaceship has the exact same duration as on Earth

This doesn’t particularly suggest a clear experiment. What measurement could determine if 1 sec tick on a clock inside the spaceship has the exact same duration as on Earth?
Since this does not suggest a clear experiment then there may be disagreement about it.

this would then imply that when the spaceship returns and becomes stationary on Earth no time dilation effect would have been recorded from the clocks inside the spaceship relative to that of Earth? Therefore, the spaceship and its astronauts would not have aged differently (i.e. half the time in our case) than on Earth

This suggests a standard twins-scenario measurement. This is a clear measurement and there is no disagreement that the travelling twin returns younger. This type of experiment has been performed with clear results matching the relativistic predictions.

please clarify? Which of the two answers is the correct one? Will SR time dilation affect aging of the spaceship and its occupants?

The first is correct, the second is not clear enough to be either correct or incorrect. The twins scenario is correct and has been experimentally confirmed.
